# How to sort file list, that have same names, but different extensions

Tags: linux

I have a folder with both `.doc` files and `.pdf` files. Some of these have the same name eg `test.doc` and `test.pdf`. I wish to sort the folder to only retain the `.doc` versions (if infact there are duplicates) as the `.pdf` versions are no longer needed

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir -p PDF
for f in *.pdf ; do
    bn=$(basename -- "$f" .pdf)
    [ -e "$bn.doc" ] && mv -- "$f" PDF/
done
```

I'll leave it up to you to `rm -rf PDF/` - i like to leave the irrevocable step as late as possible in any potentially risky procedure.

If you prefer to just go ahead and delete them, then:

```
for f in *.pdf ; do
    [ -e "$(basename -- "$f" .pdf).doc" ] && rm -f -- "$f"
done
```

This version doesn't bother setting the intermediary variable "$bn" - either way works...the former is IMO more "readable" and is also better if you have any other uses for the file's basename.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for i in `ls | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d'.' -f1 | uniq -d`
do
   rm -r $PWD/$i".pdf"
done
```

Warning: Your file name should contain only one dot(.) (i.e.,) finename.extension and should be executed within the same directory if you executing same snippet.

Comment: That makes a lot of assumptions. Like that the file names and current directory path doesn't  contain IFS characters or newline or wildcards and that the file names contain only one dot. Not sure what the `awk` part or the `-r` option are about.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to "sort" a folder to remove files. You can sort by filenames with `ls -bU | sort` or you can process the list to remove unwanted  files.

1. Delete all PDF files for which there is a DOC

   ```
   for d in *.doc; do p="${d/%.doc/.pdf}"; test -f "$p" && rm -f "$p"; done
   ```
2. Delete all PDF files

   ```
   rm -f *.pdf
   ```

Both variants handle filenames with spaces and other strange characters in them. You can test the solutions by substituting `rm` for `echo rm`.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
doc_base=(*.doc(:r)) && rm -f -- $^doc_base.pdf
```

Or:

```
setopt histsubstpattern # could go in ~/.zshrc
rm -f -- *.doc(:s/%doc/pdf)
```

To remove all pdf files, provided there's a file with the same basename but different extension (doc or other):

```
setopt histsubstpattern extendedglob
rm -f -- *.*~*.pdf(:r:s/%/pdf)
```